# asp.net arbitrary user info

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

If I am using asp.net's built-in membership provider, then how can I store arbitrary user-info while using CreateUserWizard control?

Suppose I have three types of users in my application: Student, Teacher and Staff. I want to store a flag for every user to distinguish their types while creating a user through CreateUserWizard - control.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use Profile.

Answer (score 1):

Use a user profile to store user information.  It looks as though you are creating a role based on the person logging in in this case.  If this is true perhaps using / setting a role is the better approach on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a look at this long series on the Asp.Net Membership, Roles, and Profiles. It should have more then enough information to get you what you are trying to do.

[Part 6](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx) specifically covers the Profile portion.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @klabranche, using roles is the perfect solution for "types of users" (Student, Teacher and Staff).

I haven't done it with CreateUserWizard, but it should be pretty straightforward: [How to Add Users to Roles Using the CreateUserWizard](http://www.garyshort.org/blog/archive/2008/03/22/how-to-add-users-to-roles-using-the-createuserwizard.aspx).